# Magento - reorder onepage checkout

Tags: php, magento, checkout, onestepcheckout

Hi I am trying to reoder my onepage checkout. First I am trying this by modifying the core files and when this works, I am overriding them in my files, so I can update them. I can reorder my onepage checkout to the desired form:

```
    'shipping_method','shipping','billing','payment', 'review'
```

My checkout is now in this desired output, but the shipping method is not loaded. I Modified the files:

Block/onepage.phtml -

```
 $stepCodes = array('shipping_method','shipping','billing','payment', 'review');
```

opcheckout.js -

```
  this.steps = ['shipping_method','shipping','billing','payment', 'review'];

  this.currentStep = 'shipping_method';
```

What did I do wrong, that the shipping method is not loaded?

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but the reason your shipping methods must not be loaded is because shipping methods depend on the shipping address (mainly country). So if you haven't set your shipping address then Magento doesn't know what shipping methods are applicable.